# Where/How to Build a Ball Joint

Tags: kinematics

I am trying to mimic the behavior of the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pfnKuKy6Lg

I'm interested in the ball joints connected to the platform.  I've searched for them online, but I only find ball joint rod ends that are at a 90 degree angle with a large shank.  Are these types of joints in the video custom made or can they be purchased?  I've seen them on some 3D printers too.

Comment: "Inline ball joint", and other names which are much more ambiguos. The likely problem is you need to find better stores to search...one where you can easily by picture *cough* McMaster Carr *cough*

Comment: That did it!  I found this on McMaster which hopefully does the trick.
https://www.mcmaster.com/catalog/127/1364

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is CGI.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to DKNguyen, I think I found what I was looking for on McMaster https://www.mcmaster.com/8412K41/

[image]

CGW edits: adding a cutaway diagram for completeness
[image]